# Finding minimum and do some calculations on list using heap data structure

Tags: python, sorting, heap

I'm studying heaps and tried a question in hackarank.

The problem is to find the number of times taken to achieve a certain value K in a list. If any value are smaller than K: then first two minimum values are added and new value is placed instead of those two values.

I've finished coding the solution. However please state any improvements I can do to make the code run faster.

My code:

```
import heapq as heap

data = map (int, raw_input ().strip ().split ())
N, K = data [0], data [1]

cookies = map (int, raw_input ().strip ().split ()) 
heap.heapify (cookies)
numOps = 0
possibility = False

while cookies [0] < K:
    if N == 1:
        possibility = True
        break
    leastSweetCookies = heap.nsmallest (2, cookies)
    heap.heapreplace (cookies, leastSweetCookies [0] + 2 * leastSweetCookies [1])
    heap.heappop (cookies)
    numOps += 1
    N -= 1
if possibility == False: print numOps
else: print -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three lines:

```
leastSweetCookies = heap.nsmallest (2, cookies)
heap.heapreplace (cookies, leastSweetCookies [0] + 2 * leastSweetCookies [1])
heap.heappop (cookies)
```

are equivalent to:

```
sw1 = heap.heappop(cookies);
sw2 = heap.heappop(cookies);
heap.heappush(cookies, sw1 + 2*sw2);
```

In your code, the call to `nsmallest` will potentially iterate the entire heap to find the 2 smallest items. Then it's an O(log n) to replace the top element, and O(log n) to pop the smallest.

In the replacement code, it's O(log n) for each of the two pops, and O(log n) for the push. So:

your code: O(n) + O(log n) + O(log n)

my code: O(log n) + O(log n) + O(log n)